# Should I use Recipe Schema Structure for my Shoe site?

Tags: schema.org

As we know that, we can use [Google Schema - Recipe](http://schema.org/Recipe) to display five star rating and image in google search result, but in case my site isn't cooking site (A shopping shoe), Should I use this Schema Structure? Why?

Comment: Are you aware that Google offers other rich cards (besides the one for recipes)? If yes, what is your thought process here, *why* would you want to use `Recipe` for shoes?

Comment: Why do you want to use structured data on you shoe website at all?   There is no general benefit to having some type of structured data on your site.   You only benefit when somebody (like a search engine) consumes it and does something useful with it (like showing star ratings in the search results because you use review schema).    It is pointless to try to find some type of structured data that fits just so you can check off "using structured data".

Answer (score 3):

Recipe Schema is for food recipes, is there any reason why you wouldn't use the correct [Product Schema](http://schema.org/Product) instead? The description for it literally mentions shoes after all. :)

> Any offered product or service. For example: a pair of shoes; a
>   concert ticket; the rental of a car; a haircut; or an episode of a TV
>   show streamed online.

Comment: *...it literally mentions shoes after all...* You are starting to sound like me! Cracked me up. Cheers!!